# C - recursive permutations in lexicographical order

Tags: c, recursion, permutation, alphabetical, lexicographic

I am trying to make permutations of strings with up to 8 characters. The problem is it must be done with recursion and it must be in lexicographical order. I found one solution with the recursion but it only works for 4 characters max. After that, it starts to mess up again.

```
void swap(char* a, char* b){
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void recursion(char* arr, int start, int n){
    if (start == (n-1)){
        printf("%s\n", arr);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = start; i < n; i++){
        recursion(arr, start+1, n);
        swap(arr+start+1, arr+n-1);
        int j = start+1;
        while (j < n && arr[start] > arr[j]){
            j++;
        }

        if (j >= n){
            continue;
        }
        swap(arr+start, arr+j);
    }
    swap(arr+start+1, arr+n-1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char arr[9];
    char charakter;
    int m = 0;
    while (scanf("%c", &charakter) != EOF){
        if (charakter == '\n'){
            break;
        }
        else if (isalpha(charakter) || isdigit(charakter)){
            arr[m] = charakter;
            m++;
        }

        else{
            fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
            return 100;
        }        
    }

    arr[m] = '\0';

    int n = strlen(arr);
    int start = 0;
    recursion(arr, start, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea how to fix the recursion function?

Comment: Can you give ax example?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is strange, have a look [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) and here a fix:

```
void recursion(char *arr, int start, int n) {
  if (start == n) {
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    return;
  }

  for (int i = start; i < n; i++) {
    swap(arr + start, arr + i);
    recursion(arr, start + 1, n);
    swap(arr + start, arr + i);
  }
}
```

here a proper solution:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void recursion(char *str, size_t n, size_t max) {
  if (n < max) {
    recursion(str, n + 1, max);
    for (size_t i = n + 1; i < max; i++) {
      char tmp = str[i];
      str[i] = str[n];
      str[n] = tmp;
      recursion(str, n + 1, max);
      str[n] = str[i];
      str[i] = tmp;
    }
  } else {
    printf("%s\n", str);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  char str[42];
  errno = 0;
  if (scanf("%41s", str) != 1) {
    if (errno != 0) {
      perror("scanf()");
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "no input");
    }
    return 1;
  }

  recursion(str, 0, strlen(str));
}
```